# 2002 Yamaha YZF R1- Fault code 15

Tags: motorcycle, sensor, yamaha, throttle, code

I have fault code 15 on my display. Checked the TPS, it has the right resistance on all cables combinations. Also correct voltage on yellow - black when its attached to wire harness and the ignition switch is on. Also measured the resistance from the wire harness connector to ECU connector and no broken cables in wire harness.

What do I miss?

Why does my ECU still sees that there is something wrong and sends the fault code 15 to my display?

Comment: Did you ever find the problem with your fault code 15, im having the same issue on my 02 r1

Answer (score 3):

**The fault code is related to your TPS**

Your TPS is a throttle position sensor.  The fault code is not necessarily indicative of a broken wire although it could be.  It sounds as though you have validated some of the wiring to your ECU but there are some additional checks you can perform to ensure that the issue is indeed your TPS.

- Check your wiring FROM your TPS to your ECE for continuity
- Disconnect your battery and see if the code comes back.  Perhaps by disconnecting some of your devices and reconnecting them you have created a better connection between connectors and solved the issue.
- Clean the connection points from the TPS to your main harness

If none of these additional options work I would flow to procuring a new TPS, it's located on the side of your carburetor where the butterfly shaft exits on the left side of the bank.